# Why the the input length is 1?

Tags: reactjs

The user has the possibility to generate input fields in order to enter a value, but what I want is the input length to be at 0.

```
const [list, setList] = useState([{ name: "" }]);


  const handleClick = () => {
    setList([...list, { name: "" }]);
  };

  console.log(inputList) // in the console it shows the length 1

  const handleItemChanged = (event, index) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const newlist = [...list];


    newlist[index].items = value;
    list(newlist);
  };
```

So when the user goes to this component, it is shown an input field, and that's because the length as initial is 1.

How can I make it the length 0?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of declairation you already set a item.
So if you want to the list length will be 0, at initial
then do it as blank aray. like

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you always have `[{items:''}]` at least in your array, which is array with one entry, therefore length 1.